# Can you roll a dice pool or multiple dice rolls with only one die?

Tags: statistics, dice, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

Say I'm playing Vampire: The Requiem and I need to roll 5 d10's. Can I roll a d10 5 times instead of having 5 d10's? Can I split it up if I must, so if I only had 4 d10's could I roll the 4, then roll one a second time to get 5? Does using this method mess up the probability or something of similar nature?

Answer (score 21):

That's fine. Everything you described is exactly equivalent:

- Rolling one d10 five times and writing down the results each time.
- Rolling two to four d10, writing down the results, then picking up however many and rolling them again until you have five results written down.
- Rolling five d10 all at once.

All of them result, overall, in five dice rolls being made, and five results being recorded. There is no difference in probability whether you use one dice to do it, or five. The only difference is that rolling all five at once might save you more time. (Also, rolling fistfuls of dice can be pretty fun!)

Comment: Well, it may also be easier to check results with 5 dice rolled rather than 1 die rolled five times. But as far as probabilities goes, it's definitely equivalent.

Comment: Plenty of times I've seen a  player come to a game with only a standard 7-set and needing to use scratch paper for running totals.

Answer (score 13):

**There is no change in the probability of rolling 5 dice once, or 1 die five times (or any other combination).**

Attention: If your game allows you to "split the dice pool," make sure that the player commits to the number of dice to be rolled *before* seeing the results as they occur. This is important, for example, where the dice pool is to be split at the beginning of the round for use during the course of the round: with some dice for attack, some for defense and the remainder for movement.